# AngularJS: No entiendo lo que hace

Tags: angularjs, eventos, class, click

No entiendo que hacen estos dos `ng`. `Pulsera` es el `controller` pero no se si apuntan a él, o a un `.html`.

```
*ng-click="pulsera.go('medico.detallesPaciente.pulsera', {id: pulsera.paciente.id})
```

---

```
*ng-class="{active: ( 'medico.detallesPaciente.pulsera' | routeSegmentEqualsTo )}"
```

Necesitaría una breve explicación. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **ng-click:** Está apuntando al controller `pulsera`, esto quiere decir que dentro de `pulsera` controller hay una función llamada `go`, ésta función recibe 2 parámetros, 1 un `string` y otro un `objeto`.
  **Poco más te puedo ayudar sin ver lo que hace la función `go`.**
- **ng-class:** Aplica la clase `active` si la expresión es `true`. En esa expresión está comprobando, con el filter `routeSegmentEqualsTo`, si la ruta actual es igual `medico.detallesPaciente.pulsera`.

Información del filtro: [angular-route-segment](https://github.com/artch/angular-route-segment)